# PostgreSQL - Loop Over Rows to Fill NULL Values

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named `players` which has the following data

```
+------+------------+
| id   | username   |
|------+------------|
| 1    | mike93     |
| 2    | james_op   |
| 3    | will_sniff |
+------+------------+
```

desired result:

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | username   | uniqueId   |
|------+------------+------------|
| 1    | mike93     | PvS3T5     |
| 2    | james_op   | PqWN7C     |
| 3    | will_sniff | PHtPrW     |
+------+------------+------------+
```

I need to create a new column called `uniqueId`. This value is different than the default serial numeric value. `uniqueId` is a unique, NOT NULL, 6 characters long text with the prefix "P".

In my migration, here's the code I have so far:

```
ALTER TABLE players ADD COLUMN uniqueId varchar(6) UNIQUE;

(loop comes here)

ALTER TABLE players ALTER COLUMN uniqueId SET NOT NULL;
```

and here's the SQL code I use to generate these unique IDs

```
SELECT CONCAT('P', string_agg (substr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', ceil (random() * 62)::integer, 1), ''))
FROM   generate_series(1, 5);
```

So, in other words, I need to create the new column without the `NOT NULL` constraint, loop over every already existing row, fill the NULL value with a valid ID and eventually add the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you have to do - but also must add a fallback in case the formula produces a collision - duplicate "unique" IDs.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Correct, I already have that logic handled in my server-side code but unfortunately still need to figure out how to do it SQL wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory it should be enough to run:

```
update players
  set unique_id = (SELECT CONCAT('P', string_agg ...))
;
```

However, Postgres will not re-evaluate the expression in the SELECT for every row, so this generates a unique constraint violation. One workaround is to create a function (which you might want to do anyway) that generates these fake IDs

```
create function generate_fake_id()
returns text
as
$$
  SELECT CONCAT('P', string_agg (substr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', ceil (random() * 62)::integer, 1), ''))
  FROM   generate_series(1, 5)
$$
language sql
volatile;
```

Then you can update your table using:

```
update players
  set unique_id = generate_fake_id()
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8651fde0528b3ee83c776cb97659cee1)

Comment: This does the trick perfectly. I do wanna bring up what @IVOGELOV commented though, is there a proper way to modify this so that collisions aren't a problem?

Comment: You should use a "generator" that is _guaranteed_ to generate unique IDs  (which yours is not)